# Allow bookmarking for reputation-less users

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bookmarks

I am on the SE Android app daily, trying to absorb as much as humanly possible, but I don't have the requisite reputation to vote on threads or an individual's answers. It would be incredibly useful - practical even - to have the ability to bookmark topics that are treated at length; threads which I, and perhaps other users, would like to revisit easily.

That I am aware of, there isn't a way to review the history of visited threads from within the app or the website, which makes the likelihood of locating specific threads again extremely difficult. Therefore, I would like to request the addition of in-app bookmarks or the ability to navigate through my history of visits to Stack Exchange, et al. topics/threads.

Answer (score 6):

Does the favourite  (sorry, favorite) button on questions not work for you? Questions you've marked as favourites should appear in a list in your profile on each site.

The Android app easily supports marking questions as favourites, but you're best off using a browser to navigate your favourite questions.

Comment: Is it not easy to browse favourites on the android app? It's probably easier on the iOS app than it is on the main site (or at least *as* easy anyway)

Comment: Favourites is a relatively decent option, though it took a while to track where in one's profile they're tucked away (via mobile browser; desktop mode only). Another problem with accessing favourites from a browser is the OpenID fragmentation across the family of Stack Exchange sites; nonexistent inside the Android app where one navigates easily between all sites with a single login - yet accumulated favourites are inaccessible.